# ROS Package for raspberry pi camera B (from waveshare)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know ros package for raspberry pi camera B ( from [waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/rpi-camera-b.htm) )? Can I use raspicam_node from UbiquityRobotics for this type of camera?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314879/ros-package-for-raspberry-pi-camera-b-(from-waveshare)/) by [mlsdpk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39887/mlsdpk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1